# I can´t find the load_data function from rasa_nlu.training_data

Tags: python, chatbot, rasa-nlu

**Rasa NLU version** (e.g. `0.7.3`): rasa-nlu-0.11.3

**Used backend / pipeline** : spacy_sklearn

**Operating system** : Windows 10

**Issue**:
I am trying to follow the sample code for training as stated in the rasa website.

```
from rasa_nlu.training_data import load_data
from rasa_nlu.config import RasaNLUConfig
from rasa_nlu.model import Trainer

training_data = load_data('data/examples/rasa/demo-rasa.json')
trainer = Trainer(RasaNLUConfig("sample_configs/config_spacy.json"))
trainer.train(training_data)
model_directory = trainer.persist('./projects/default/')
```

But I can't find the load_data function from rasa_nlu.training_data, therefore, I get the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-07f2f1a6c2ac> in <module>()
----> 1 from rasa_nlu.training_data import load_data
      2 from rasa_nlu.config import RasaNLUConfig
      3 from rasa_nlu.model import Trainer

ImportError: cannot import name 'load_data'
```

Can someone please help me?

Answer (score 7):

use `from rasa_nlu.converters import load_data` instead of `from rasa_nlu.training_data import load_data`

See
http://rasa-nlu.readthedocs.io/en/latest/python.html

https://nlu.rasa.ai/0.11.3/python.html

Answer (score 1):

**Solution**

```
from rasa.shared.nlu.training_data.loading import load_data
```

More info: https://github.com/RasaHQ/rasa/issues/1536

Comment: Hello yattara, could you please expand your answer and add the relevant parts of the link you mentioned, so that the answer is complete by itself?